# How to get realtime stdout from a celery task?

Tags: python-3.x, django, celery, django-celery, celery-task

I have a Django project in which i'm running some background tasks with celery, one of my goal is to show real-time stdout of the running task so that the user can see the progress. the issue is that i get the stdout of the process only when it is finished executing (all is dumped at once).

Views.py

```
def run_script(request, file_type, file_id):
    run_features.delay(arguments)
    return
```

Tasks.py

```
@shared_task
def run_features(arguments):
    process = subprocess.Popen(arguments, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()

        while True:
            output = process.stdout.readline()
            if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
                break
            if output:
                print(output)
                async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
                    'output_group',
                    {
                        'type': 'send_output',
                        'output': output.strip()
                    }
                )

        process.wait()
        return process.returncode
```

Celery INFO

```
 -------------- celery@ritik v5.3.1 (emerald-rush)
--- ***** ----- 
-- ******* ---- Linux-6.5.0-25-generic-x86_64-with-glibc2.35 2024-03-21 09:30:54
- *** --- * --- 
- ** ---------- [config]
- ** ---------- .> app:         Automation:0x7e2bb4073280
- ** ---------- .> transport:   redis://localhost:6379/0
- ** ---------- .> results:     disabled://
- *** --- * --- .> concurrency: 8 (prefork)
-- ******* ---- .> task events: OFF (enable -E to monitor tasks in this worker)
--- ***** ----- 
 -------------- [queues]
                .> celery           exchange=celery(direct) key=celery
```

Expectation - I get the stdout, line by line, while the task is running.
Actual result - I get the stdout, all at once, after the subprocess is finished.

Also, I'm  not sure if this is a django problem or celery problem.

Thankyou for any help! This is my first stackOverflow question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! just use Pexpect.spawn() instead of subprocess.Popen()

```
# Start the process
child = pexpect.spawn(command, args, encoding='utf-8', timeout=180)

# Log the output
while True:
    try:
        line = child.readline()
        if not line:
            break
        print(line.strip())
    except pexpect.EOF:
        break

child.wait()
child.close()

return None
```